# Does the term CFLAGS have any significance in Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I was wondering if I was making a makefile. And instead of using CFLAGS I use CFLAGS_1, would this be valid. This is because trying to use logic (using ifeq and else) where if I had to compile two sets of files e.g A.c and B.c but B.c depends on a shared object, so I want to change the CFLAGS used for it. However, I am having trouble getting it to work.

```
${PROG}: ${OBJS}
     ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${PROG} ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}
```

Comment: What are you trying exactly and what isn't working exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Using `CFLAGS_1` is fine, it just won't work for any of the built-in rules that use `CFLAGS` already.

And while that answers the question you actually asked I feel like the question you didn't ask is the more relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "target-specific" variable:  a variable whose value depends on what file we are building:

`A : CFLAGS :=` ...

`B : CFLAGS :=` ...

```
PROG := A B
${PROG}:...
    here you can use ${CFLAGS} and it will be the one assigned for the target you are building
```